# Regex to match anything between 2 symbols starting from the end of a file?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I want what is between the colons, but I need to match from the end because the previous content may have colons and mess things up.

something that uses a colon:

something else that uses a colon:

:IWantWhatIsInHere:

something

something

Comment: What is the exact question? The title kind of does not relate to the example..

Comment: You're right, I clarified (I think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, assuming you have a string named `text`:

```
import re
data = re.search(r'.*:([^:]*):', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

The greedy `.*` at the beginning of the regex ensures that your match will start at the last `:` possible, to meet your "from the end of the file" requirement.  The `re.DOTALL` flag is there so that the `.*` can also match line break characters.

The `:([^:]*):` portion of the regex is where you will actually match "IWantWhatIsInHere", `[^:]*` means "match any number of characters that are not `:`", and the parentheses will save the match to a capture group.

After we have found the match we call `group(1)` on it to get the contents of the first capture group, this will be the data you want.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. May I ask what the r before the regex does?

Comment: `r` before a string means it is a "raw string".  this prevents escape sequences such as `'\n'` from being translated into something else.  if you do `print r'\n'` it will print a backslash and an 'n' instead of just printing a newline.  It's a good habit to use raw strings for regexes because of all the `'\'`s you often need

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> tgt='''\
... something that uses a colon:
... 
... something else that uses a colon:
... 
... :IWantWhatIsInHere:
... 
... something
... 
... something'''
>>> re.search(r':([^:]*):[^:]*$',tgt,re.DOTALL).group(1)
'IWantWhatIsInHere'
```

It [works](http://www.regex101.com/r/mY4zL3) with the end of line anchor.